# What is the difference in the below code on object creation, threading, and accessing by methods of same class

Tags: java

How is the two variables differ on memory allocation, during threading and accessing by the methods of ClassB. 
When I create multiple objects of ClassB, does var1 and var2 created everytime.

```
public class ClassB {
    ClassC var1 = new ClassC();//Without static , When is the object created. 
    static ClassC var2 = new ClassC();//With static, When is this object created. 
    public static void method()  {

    }

}
class ClassC {

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198693/what-is-the-difference-between-a-static-variable-and-a-dynamic-variable-in-java

Comment: Do a bit of research, this is not something you should be asking here. To put it shortly: `var1` will be created everytime you create an instance of `ClassB` just before the constructor goes through. `var2` will be created once after compilation upon class loading.

Answer (score 0):

**static variable** will only create once when **class**(`ClassB`) is loaded by **class loader**.

and for **class fields** it will init when **object** is created(`new ClassB()`).

so for `var2` it will only create once, and `var1` this variable will create everytime when `new ClassB()`.